# I've this error "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist" when I run ajax to load another file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I started to learn Ajax and this was the basic example to run ajax so what should I do when I face these "Unchecked runtime.lastError" errors ?

I tried Chrome extension wappalyzer but same problem and I am using xampp server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Ajax</title>
    <script>
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if(xhr.readystate == 4) 
            {
                document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhr.open('GET','content.html', true);
        function sendajax() {
            xhr.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Welcome to Ajax</h3>
    <button onclick="sendajax();">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="ajax"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The same code worked in course that I'm studying and I believe the problem in my browser or server i do not know.

Comment: Given this file is `index.html` and resides in the docroot of your XAMPP server - then it is most likely the case that you have placed the `content.html` file in a different location on your server. As written, `content.html` must be in the same folder on your server as the `index.html` file. (since you are using a relative path to the `content.html` file).

Comment: @RandyCasburn No content.html and index.html in the same folder